# How can I get an IAP receipt from SKPaymentTransaction?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, in-app-purchase

How can I obtain the In-App purchase receipt from a completed purchase on the user's iOS device? After a purchase is made, we need to verify the receipt immediately after the purchase is made (preferably in the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`). Otherwise, when we try to separately verify the local receipt...it's out of date!

Here's my transaction observer below:

```
extension StoreManager: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
  func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])    {
    print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");
    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
      // check object is a transaction first
      if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
        switch trans.transactionState {
        case .Purchased:
          print("Product Purchased");
          SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
          // invoke any callback waiting to be called
          purchaseCallbackHolder?([trans.pseudoReceipt]) // here is where I'd like to extract the receipt associated with the transaction
          purchaseCallbackHolder = nil
          break;

        case .Failed:
          print("Purchased Failed");
          SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
          break;
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Note in the above I've written the code `trans.pseudoReceipt`. The problem here is I can't pull any receipt from the transaction. However, when I check the local receipt...it's not updated! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try issuing a `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` and wait for it to complete before reading the local receipt.  Best practice is to validate the receipt with the AppStore through your own server.